# A Tag Click Detection

Tags: html, css, browser

I've recently come across an issue while trying to create a stylized link. The link is styled to look like a flattened physical button. When the user clicks the link we want it to behave somewhat like a button so the 'button' shifts down 4 pixels.

I'm doing this by having a div within an a tag that has a border on the bottom. When the a tag is :active the border on the bottom of the div is made smaller by 4 pixels and there is a padding added to the top of the a tag to shift the 'button' div down.

**The Problem:**

If the user clicks at the very top of the div the displacement of the 4 pixels causes the link not to fire **even though the user is still clicking on the a tag**.

I've tried various iterations of this: 'animating' the div via position relative, a border on the a tag and even hiding/showing a spacer div (still within the a tag). Nothing works (tried it in different browsers just to see if that was it, no help). I'm wondering why this is.

Here's a link to a JSBin providing an example of the problem: http://jsbin.com/eminuk/4/edit

In the example I made the background-color of the a tag red so that it's very clear. Have the console open (each element is outing to the console when it's clicked). Click at the very top of the grey button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while, but I found a solution! Just change

```
.btn-link:active { padding-top: 4px; }
```

to

```
.btn-link:active { padding-top: 4px; margin-top:-4px; }
```

It changes the animation just a little (it kind of moves the background up instead of the front down), but it is pretty much the same and completely clickable

Comment: Interesting. I came up a solution as well (although it was a bit more complex) of adding an absolutely positioned div within the a tag that covers the button.

I still would really like to know why a click event doesn't fire in my first example.

Comment: It's because you add padding to the top of the element BEFORE the link is fired (on mousedown while the link is fired on mouseup). In that space where you added padding the element is not there anymore, and you can't hyperlink padding for obvious reasons

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this instead...

```
<a href="#" class="my-btn">
  <img src="my-btn-image.png" alt="">
</a>
```

and css...

```
.my-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
}

.my-btn img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.my-btn:active img {
  top: 4px;
}
```

In my mind though, a better way of creating an "animated" click on buttons is to use a small button sprite. In the case below, you would create an image 75px tall, with each various state (up, over/hover, and down/click) taking up a 25px chuck of the image.

```
<a href="#" class="my-btn">My Button</a>
```

and css...

```
.my-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url(my-btn-image.png);
  background-position: top;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

.my-btn:hover {
  background-position: center center;
}

.my-btn:active {
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

note: background-position can be set at pixel values (0 0, -25px 0, and -50px 0) if you prefer.